# Display text on hover image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display text on hover image. The problem is that the images are located in a table. I saw many examples, but when I'm trying, the text appears under the image and not above.
What can I do in that situation? Thanks

html:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <img class="table_photo" src="" /> 
                  <p>first text</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                <img class="table_photo" src="" /> 
                </td>   
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <img class="table_photo" src="" /> 
                </td>
                <td>
                <img class="table_photo" src="" /> 
                </td>   
            </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table   {
    width:590px;
    height:590px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;

}
.table_photo    {
    position: relative;
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;


}
```

Comment: text is placed after the image?

Comment: and where is the text in HTML?

Comment: Please check the link below.
Answered in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036531/how-to-show-text-in-image-hover

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` alongwith a `z-index` should work.

Try giving your text higher z-index than the image.

Answer (score 0):

table is position absolute and table content (image with class=".table_photo") is position relative this is wrong.

Position absolute should use inside the relative position. And z-index value should be high for which is comes on top.

Comment: Table is position absolute because it placed inside another div. How can I put a div in absolute position inside a div in absolute position, inside a div in relative position?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary that you place your text under the image in your HTML. Here is a working snippet.

```js
$(".table_photo").hover(function() {
  $(".imgText").show(1000);
});

$(".table_photo").mouseout(function() {
  $(".imgText").hide(1000);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 590px;
  height: 590px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.imgText {
  display: none;
}
.table_photo {
  position: relative;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="imgText">first text</p>
      <img class="table_photo" src="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="table_photo" src="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="table_photo" src="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="table_photo" src="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css`

adding z-index will fix the issue

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
td {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
td img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table_photo + p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.table_photo:hover + p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="table_photo" src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/any" />
      <p>first text</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="table_photo" src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/any" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="table_photo" src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/any" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="table_photo" src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/any" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the text appear at the bottom of the table and not inside the image. How can I do this?

Comment: inside the image means at the center of the td

Comment: The text is flickering inside the td while I move the mouse inside. There is a solution?