# hover clickable image description not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a clickable image when on hover I would like to display a short description about it. 
I have a tried a method using CSS and jQuery but it seems like it glitters when I hover instead of remaining on a steady state(static).

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="project">
    <img src="images/valencia.png"/>
</a>
<a href="#" class="description">
    <p>In this website you find information about sport and gastronomy in Valencia. It was built for the Erasmus+ Project.</p>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```css
a.project img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
a.description {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.description {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 90px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
a.description p {
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a.project img').mouseover(function(){
    $('a.description').css("visibility","visible");
});
$('a.project img').mouseout(function(){
    $('a.description').css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate.  I've posted your code into a fiddle and the hover effect seems to be working exactly as one might expect. https://jsfiddle.net/f7fqcprs/

Comment: Have a look at this and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971757/how-to-display-text-over-a-faded-image-on-hover-using-jquery

Comment: @RobertC , well as you can see when you move your mouse on the image, the text glitters , I want it static.

Comment: Not seeing anything I would call a 'glitter' on my end.

Comment: @Danieboy, I modified my code using that as example and it works! thank you very much !

Comment: I've added it as an answer. So you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that might help you solve the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971934/3585278

> It's good to remember that if you're handling how things look, chances are it should be done in CSS (which will make your life easier in the long run).
>
> I've mocked up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/HAcE2/
>
> You basically need to create a box that appears when you hover. By using position:absolute you can get the box to appear over the top and using CSS we can get it to appear when we hover over.

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color:#f00;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
}

img {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try `.hover` instead:

```
$('a.project img').hover(function(){
    $('a.description').css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Rather than testing for `.mouseover` and `.mouseout`.